# Uniqueness in the representation of non-empty basic open sets in the Vietoris topology

Tags: general-topology

For a $T_1$ topological space $X$, denote by $2^X$ the collection of closed and non-empty subsets of $X$. If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $U_1,\dots,U_n$ are non-empty open subsets of $X$, define $$\langle U_1,\dots,U_n \rangle := \left\{A\in 2^X : A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_i \ \wedge \ \forall 1\leq i \leq n \left(A\cap U_i \neq\emptyset\right)\right\}.$$ My specific question is the following: suppose that $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $U_1,\dots,U_n,V_1,\dots,V_m$ are non-empty open subsets of $X$ such that $U_i\neq U_j$, $V_i\neq V_j$, and $\langle U_1,\dots,U_n \rangle = \langle V_1,\dots,V_m \rangle$. Is it then true that $m=n$ and $\{U_1,\dots,U_n\} = \{V_1,\dots,V_m \}$?

What I do know for certain is that, from the equality $\langle U_1,\dots,U_n \rangle = \langle V_1,\dots,V_m \rangle$, the following three things can be proved:

1. $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^{m} V_j$.
2. For every $1\leq i \leq n$ there is $1\leq j\leq m$ such that $V_j \subseteq U_i$.
3. For every $1\leq j\leq m$ there is $1\leq i \leq n$ such that $U_i \subseteq V_j$.

What I don't know yet is if these three conditions imply what I stated in the question above.

Comment: Nothing keeps the $U_i$ from repeating.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that detail.